# Javascript File Path to be included via content_for in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-for

I have read that if you want to include a javascript file specific to your view you can use content_for and yield functions of ruby. Following is sample code to do it. I want to know what is the path where it will look for forms.js.

```
<% content_for :javascript_includes do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "forms.js" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Using `content_for` has no implications on the lookup path for assets.

Rails will look in multiple places, as is does for all assets. In case of `forms.js` it will look for

1. `app/assets/javascripts/forms.js`
2. `lib/assets/javascripts/forms.js`
3. `vendor/assets/javascripts/forms.js`

(If not found in one of these locations, it will proceed looking in all required gems, which provide a Rails Engine. Within these gems it will again look at the locations given above.)